# SQL Sharepoint Integration thru SSIS using oData Source Connector driver

Tags: ssis, odata, ssis-2012

SSIS SP Connection using OData connector.
I was able to connect to Sharepoint site fine and was able to see the data thru preview and all.. but when i execute the task i get below error.

[OData Source [2]] Error: The OData Source was unable to process the data. Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Note: Visual Studio 2012 with BI template not sure how different is that from SSDT 2012. When i go try to open SSDT 2012, i get VS 2010 shell, that's why i use VS 2012 with Business Intelligence template thinking that maybe same as SSDT 2012. If this has to do something with error message i get above.

Task:
OData Source with SP connection information
OLE DB Destination.

Let me know your thoughts!!

Comment: Any thoughts on error message.

Comment: Try setting the Project Properties / Debugging / Run64BitRuntime to False.

Answer (score 2):

I would try setting the Project Properties / Debugging / Run64BitRuntime to False.

This will run your debug executions (e.g. Execute Task, Execute Package using Visual Studio) using the 32-bit version of the OData connector.  Visual Studio (which you have used to design the task and preview the data) is a 32-bit app, so it will be using the 32-bit versions of the OData connector.

The same challenge applies to almost every connector or driver that has to be separately installed for SSIS. Typically they come in 32-bit and 64-bit flavors, with independent setup, configuration and sometimes bugs.

While I recognize that 64-bit components will generally deliver higher throughput, I have resigned to always install and use the 32-bit connectors and drivers.  I find this minimizes wasted time and frustration trying to debug and resolve these issues on multiple developer machines and servers.